# Simple table join in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm new to working with nHibernate and have inherited a project which has implemented it for accessing its database. So far I've been able to write additional single-table query methods using QueryOvery<>, but I'm finding the logic behind table joins perplexing.

I want to implement the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.FILE_ID, f.COMPANY_ID, f.FILE_META_ID, (etc...)
FROM AUDIT.FILE_INSTANCE f
INNER JOIN AUDIT.FILE_INSTANCE_REPORTING_PERIOD p ON p.FILE_ID = f.FILE_ID
WHERE p.REPORTING_PERIOD_ID BETWEEN 20150101 AND 20151304
  AND FILE_STATUS != 'CANCELLED';
```

In this example, the reporting period ids would be parameters. Please note that they are integers, not dates, and the DISTINCT clause is important. How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you try something with NHibernate? Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your classes but if i would have written it, it would look like this:

```
var results = session.QueryOver<FileInstance>()
    .Where(fi => fi.Status == FileStatus.Canceled)
    .JoinQueryOver(fi => fi.ReportingPeriods)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(period => period.Id).Between(20150101, 20151304)
    .Transform(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
```